# Como apagar uma musica na minha biblioteca usando a API Spotify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Eu tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
   $.ajax({                     
                    //url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks?ids=1ftBvRj542ol7LT1A0EtL7',
                    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks',
                    method:"delete",                        
                    scope: "user-library-modify",
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                        'Content-Type':'application/json'                           
                    },      
                    data:{'Id':'1ftBvRj542ol7LT1A0EtL7'},
                    json: true,                                             
                    success: function(response) {   
                        Console.log(response);
                        /*for(var k in response.items){
                            i += 1;
                            item.push('<li class="ui-state-default" id="m_'+response.items[k].track.id+'">'+response.items[k].track.name + '</li>');
                        }
                        item.push('</ul>');
                        //$('#teste')
                        //userProfilePlaceholder.innerHTML = userProfileTemplate(response);
                        userProfilePlaceholder.innerHTML = item.join("");
                        //console.log(userProfilePlaceholder);

                        */

                    }       
                });
```

Mas o parametro **data** nao está correto:

```
    data:{'Id':'1ftBvRj542ol7LT1A0EtL7'},
```

Pois da o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro]

Comment: Tente trocar `json: true` por `dataType: 'json'`. Tente também mudar `Id` por `id`.

Comment: deu o mesmo erro :(